# Russian visa registration requirement

Tags: visas, russia, registration

I will be travelling on a tourism visa to Russia soon. I plan to stay for 12 days. 
The first week I'll be staying in a friend's house. Can my friend register my visa?

Answer (score 7):

You and your friend should go to the post office within first 7 days of arrival and she/he will submit your registration.

When going to the post office, if possible, I would go to the Main regional post office, aka Pochtamt (usually, more experienced stuff). She will tell the clerk that she wishes to register an alien. The clerk will give her the paperwork, help her fill it in, file it and collect some fee. Have your passport, visa and migration card with you as photocopies of the above will be needed.

Sources:

- 27FZ [federal law number 27](http://base.garant.ru/12148419/3/)
- Instructions on [Russian Internal Affairs ministry web site](https://xn--b1aew.xn--p1ai/Deljatelnost/emvd/guvm/%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)
- Some [english site](http://waytorussia.net/RussianVisa/Registration.html)

NB!
If you travel to Russia during June 17 to July 2, 2017 (FIFA Confederation Cup) and later for 2018 World Cup, the registration rules have been made more strict by the presidential decree #202 from May,9 2017, you must register within 24 hours on arrival and you must appear [in person in GUVM](http://migrantmedia.ru/migratsionnyy-uchet-i-fifa-postanovka-na-migratsionnyy-uchet-inostrannykh-grazhdan-fifa-2017-2018/). This applies to Sochi, Kazan, Moscow, St-Petersburg and several other cities for the World Cup 2018.

Comment: @Jones do not forget to upvote

Comment: And accept :):)

Comment: @Jones see important edits if you are travelling  during June 17 to July 2, 2017 (FIFA Confederation Cup)

Answer (score 1):

When you are in Russia, you and your friend should go to the local UFMS (Federal Migration Service) to register the visa.

Depending on your nationality and the place you go to in Russia, you might need a registration support letter. Some travel agencies can provide that letter, for example Real Russia : http://realrussia.co.uk/Visas/Russian/Registration

Comment: UFMS does not exist for about a year now. It is GUPVM now.

Comment: Also, most of the registrations can be done by mail at the post office local to your friend

Comment: but what kind of documents do i need to be sent by mail?

Comment: Just take your friend to the post office. If possible, I would go to the Main Post office, aka Pochtamt. She will tell the clerk that she wishes to register an alien. The clerk will give her the paperwork, help her file it and collect some fee. Have your passport, visa and migration card with you.